# What is the Error in call function?

Tags: c#, function

I tried to call a sample function, written in c# in Unity Environment. I get this error message:

> Multi member names can not be the same as their enclosing type

This is the code I am using:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class multi : MonoBehaviour {
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        int x = 5;
        multi (x);
    }

    int multi ( int tem ){
        int ret ;
        ret = tem * 2 ; 
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A function name cannot be the same as the class name, unless the function is a constructor.

Answer (score 6):

You can't have a function "multi" in a class named "multi" unless it's a constructor.

Comment: You beat me too it!  Almost identical responses.